# Convert PDF/TIF to Excel Table using Python

Tags: python, excel, pymupdf

I'm trying to write a script that gets some information like mass, material and others from technical drawing and write it as a table.
Using pyMupdf I've got to extract the information, but I would need some help iterating it on all files in a folder and adding it to a table (csv or something like that).

```
import fitz

doc = fitz.open("test.pdf") # open document
page = doc[0] # get the 1st page of the document

mass = fitz.Rect(3240, 2230, 3348, 2246)
material = fitz.Rect(2786,2248,3050,2276)


print(page.get_textbox(material))
```

This code runs well, but as I said I would need some help to iterate in all files inside a folder and make a report of some kind.

Comment: For iterating a directory you can read this [tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-files-in-a-directory/) . As for the rest, dont know the format of the data from the PDF, if it's delimited you can write directly to a file (changing the delimiters to commas if they aren't already and that's what you want). If you want to write to an Excel table that's more work but again no idea of the data you are extracting from the PDF.